# How to scan a document on a HP deskject f4500?

Tags: printer, scanner

Is there generic software that I can download for free to quickly scan a document?

Or is there some specific software that I can download from HP?

Comment: Please Edit your post to include your OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start on this page, pick your OS and see what is available for Download. You will want the "full featured driver"

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&product=3944758&